# Masked TextBox doesn't recognize 10 as ten

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, maskedtextbox

```
For i As Integer = 0 To mtPig.Text
        MessageBox.Show(i)
    Next
```

I used a MaskedTextBox with a 2-digit mask.
If I put 10, it shows 0 and 1.
If I put 9, it shows 0-9.

Why doesn't it read the zero next to one? (10)
How can I make 10 *read as* ten?
**UPDATE:**
[image]

Comment: can you show us the image of MaskedTextBox with value of 10.

Comment: it works for me. what is your mask value?

Comment: Mask:00, Preview/PrompChar:0

Comment: Find the problem see my posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the problem is your PrompChar:0, all 0s will be treated as prompt character and discarded from value.

To solve it, do either

- change your PromptChar to _ (underscore)
- or set the MaskedTextbox property named TextMaskFormat to IncludePrompt

GOOG Luck!!

Comment: didn't know about that, I only use it on pw thing. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Integer.Parse(mtPig.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(i)
Next
```

Comment: Oh, so this hasn't got anything to do with the loop. That was there to confuse us. It's really about configuring the `MaskedTextBox`, right?

Comment: I think maybe yes since you guys gives me the same answers. I used Mask:00, Preview/PromptChar:0.. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> For loop doesn't recognize 10 as ten

No, For loop does not magically transform a string to an int.

Cast, convert, do it in code. But do not assume the compiler will magically do converts.

Comment: is it the trycast thing? can you make a sample? I can't understand how they're used every time I bump into them.

Comment: In VB it will automatically cast string into integer, long, ...and so as long as it is valid numeric string.

Answer (score 0):

you must convert it to integer then try this...:

```
Cint(mtPig.Text)
```

or

```
Convert.ToInt32(mtPig.Text)
```